# Is Cassandra Good For Banking Application?

Tags: database-design, cassandra, banking, onlinebanking

Hello fellow developer,i got very disturbing question about Cassandra,is cassandra good for Banking application which hold sensitive data?

because cassandra not using ACID but CAP,how about that?

is that any strategy to implement good and secure database in Cassandra?thanks for your response and sorry for my bad english..

:D

Comment: That's like asking if java is good for banking. Or any other language/technology.

Comment: Banking seems like a very traditional set of apps that rely on data that is easily (and efficiently) stored and manipulated in relational tables - basic customer data, your ledgers and so forth. In my opinion, this would be a classical example of when **NOT** to use one of those "NoSQL" databases...

Comment: @Oded I think he is asking about security for sensitive data. So it would be more like 'Is MySql good enough to store sensitive data in case where a lot of compliance issues are involved.' Which is perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Banking is a wide industry, with many different sorts of systems which might be considered "banking applications".  There are some for which Cassandra could be appropriate.

However, the lack of ACID support probably rules out financial transaction systems.

---

> "how about if i store something
>   sensitive like credit card
>   information,or transactional
>   information,is CAP still safe because
>   not using ACID"

Those are two different kinds of safe.

For credit card information, safety means *protecting the data from unauthorised access*.  This includes not just storage on the file system but internode communication.  I believe the latest version of Cassandra does support this, but I think it would be better for your application to encrypt/decrypt the credit card details and leave Cassandra to store the gobbledegook.

For transactional information, safety means *a consistent view of the data regardless of  access path*.  Eventual consistency is no good when we're dealing with bank balances.  Or the other hand, Cassandra would be fine for logging the transaction details in an audit trail.

Comment: how about if i store something sensitive like credit card information,or transactional information,is CAP still safe because not using ACID?thanks for your response

Comment: hei APC,thanks for your information,it really help and make me clear about this kind of problem,this is what i really means..thanks a lot,many thanks..:D